# root component swizzle in docusaurus v2 not working

Tags: docusaurus

I am trying to wrap my website with a root component: https://docusaurus.io/docs/using-themes#wrapper-your-site-with-root. I made `src/theme/Root.js` with following code in it:

```js
import React from 'react';

// Default implementation, that you can customize
function Root({children}) {
  console.log('from root');
  return <>{children}</>;
}

export default Root;
```

Now when I open up the browser console, I don't see any log. What could be the reason? I am using the classic preset with typescript support on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by deleting `.docusaurus` folder and reinstalling the contents of `node_modules`